# Instant validation with optional function for number calculation with instant result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the error instantly until the request is filled right. It means that I want the user to get the number he is typing instantly without clicking the button...

Here is my code (also found on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r76zzf9g/1)):

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="Error">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="Error"></p>
```

JS:

```
window.myFunction = function() {
var err = " is not 1000!"
  var num = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
      if (num == 1000) {
          alert("No Errors!");
      } else {
            if (num !='') {
          document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = num+err;
          }
          else {
          document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = err;
          }
      }
}
```

I'm looking for a simple solution to use a function inside until the number is calculated, so to just show the "is not 1000" while typing something other than 1000 (like 1, 100, 1001 110011 etc..) can also be fine..

Comment: `<input onchange="myFunction()" //...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `myFunction()` on `keyup` event for your input box.

```js
window.myFunction = function() {
var err = " is not 1000!"
  var num = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  if (num == 1000) {
      alert("No Errors!");
      document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    if (num !='') {
      document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = num+err;
      }
      else {
      document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = err;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNumber" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="Error">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="Error"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myNumber").on("input",myFunction);
```

Dont wait for a click, but for an input. The upper is in jquery, pure js:

```
document
  .getElementById("myNumber")
  .addEventListener("input",myFunction);
```

or inline:

```
oninput="myFunction()"
```